# what is a page state? and what and where is outputcache directive trying to save?

Tags: asp.net, outputcache, page-state

I observed that there is savepagestatetopersistencemedium method, and we can override and implement them to save them to cache or session or whatever, so what is a page state?
And I have no idea what the outputcache directive to trying to save, the viewstate or the html rendering? what is a viewstate exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two topics listed: one, which is the state of a page, and output caching, which is the [caching of the page response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  For output caching, the page lifecycle does not fire for subsequent requests of the cached page (until the cache is removed) as a way to save on performance.  Persistence is the persistence of the data on the page between requests.  ViewState is a mechanism to not lose a form's data across postbacks (since the web is stateless).  You can use the savepagestatetopersistencemedium  method to customize how the saving and loading can work, [like by compressing viewstate](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/How-To-Compress-ViewState-in-ASPNET-20-ViewState-Compression-with-SystemIOCompression.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Page state refers to the `ViewState`, which is a hidden field on the page (default) used to persist the state of controls on a page. The `PageStatePersister` allows you to change the location or medium where ViewState data is stored.

The article below provides an example demonstrating how you can use `PageStatePersister` to store ViewState data in session rather than a hidden field:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479403.aspx